# How many logic gates are there in this circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

How many logic gates are there in the following circuit? When counting how many logic gates this circuit contains, should each 3 input gate be counted as two 2 input gates?

It is something extremely simple, but I'm not quite sure about it.

Also, the circuit is probably needlessly inconvenient, but that is because it comes from an exercise on simplifying boolean expressions.

[image]

Comment: It turns on your definitions. Even for IC designers, it depends on the design rules being applied. So I'm not sure there is an absolute, everywhere-the-same true answer to your question. For example, when I'm using 7400 IC parts, I'd count a gate as "something I can isolate as a gate" in the 7400 family. That means an inverter is a gate because it requires an IC and one of its elements. And its timing is about the same as other gates, too. However, if there was an IC with a 3-in AND gate with one of the inputs inverted, then I might count one of your inverters and the 3-in AND as one gate.

Comment: "should each 3 input gate be counted as two 2 input gates" - for sure not - there exists real devices that are 3 input AND and OR gates. They are real in sense that they works faster then two connected 2 input gates - propagation delay is same as for 2 input gate.

Comment: @Jonk So it seems like it is something more relative than I thought. Interesting.

Comment: @ufok That makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: In the usual sense a 3-input gate is only a single gate. You *could* explode it in it's equivalent logic circuit but even old TTL logic simply used transistors with *multiple emitters* (https://www.nutsvolts.com/uploads/wygwam/NV_0706_Marston_Figure20.jpg). So I'd say 6 for the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the circuit is probably needlessly inconvenient

Inputs to 3-input AND gates
First  AND gate : \$xyz\$
Second AND gate : \$x\bar{y}z\$
Third  AND gate : \$z\bar{z}\bar{y}\$ : so its output is always 0

At the OR gate: 0 OR \$xzy\$ OR \$xz\bar{y}\$
Thus the output will be \$xz\$

A two input AND gate should suffice to implement this circuit.

> How many logic gates are there in the following circuit?

Six (always counted as shown). In some cases a signal and its complement are assumed to be present. In such cases you can ignore the input inverters only.

> When counting how many logic gates this circuit contains, should each
> 3 input gate be counted as two 2 input gates?

Not when counting, but when "implementing" you will find an IC package that can fit the minimized expression. If you still need a 3-input AND gate and can't find one, you can change that to two 2-input AND gates. For discrete logic, the speed is too slow to matter. For digital ICs with millions of such circuits, such decisions are made by timing tools; the designer focuses on the behavior being implemented. A library would contain 2-input and 3-input gates.

Verification:

```
BooleanMinimize[x && y && z || x && ! y && z || z && ! z && y]
```

> x && z

Comment: That was a very nice and concise explanation. Thank you.